# JavaFX runtime exception but all JavaFX jars are correctly packaged into my JAR?

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, jar

I am using Eclipse 2020.03 and Java JDK 13.

I downloaded the appropriate JARs from the JavaFx download site.

When I run my project in Eclipse, there are no errors.

However, when I export the JAR and run it, the program encounters a runtime error that reads

```
No toolkit found
```

Here is what my JAR looks like when I change the extension to a .zip and open it:
[image]

Clearly, all of the required JavaFX library JARs are in there.

I have also tried using the export mode where Eclipse extracts the library JAR source code into the exported JAR but the same error occurs.

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: I am not open to using Maven.

Comment: The jars aren't enough: you need the JavaFX runtime, which includes native components for running JavaFX applications. Your best approach is to create a native package using `jpackage`, which is included in JDK14 (though you can bundle any JDK version >=11 with the application if you like). See https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/jpackage/packaging-overview.html

Comment: I've tried to follow the guide on that site, but I don't know what to package. What exactly is the 'JavaFX runtime'? Is this the .dll files in the /bin folder in the SDK? Or is there something else that must be downloaded?

Comment: The easiest option (the one I use) is to download and unzip the jmods ("Java modules") for your platform from [here](https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/). Then you just need to create a regular jar file (with your classes and resources, no JavaFX libraries), and then you point the `--module-path` to the location of the jmods.

Comment: I'm running Windows, but the guide shows only a command for Linux/Debian modular setup. I navigated to one directory above my libraries (where the subdirectories are `bin` and `lib`), typed `jpackage --type exe --name TestApp --input lib --module-path lib --main-jar mainapp.jar` and the generated exe does not run. Do I have to export my mainapp.jar as a module instead of a runnable JAR?

Comment: Run the exe from the command line and see if there’s an error message. You can also (I think - I don’t use windows regularly) use `— type app-image` and it will create a bundle you can test more easily.

Comment: Also, I don't see how the commands listed in that tutorial are specific to any platform. Aren't they all platform-agnostic? The only things that would change are the `--type` options (`exe` or `msi` for windows) and the format of any paths. (Also, `--module-path` should be the path to the JavaFX jmods you downloaded; I don't think it can be the same as the location of the jar file you created.)